# Can't use txdb with Gormigrate

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to use [txdb](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-txdb) for migrating my database inside an isolated transaction, for the purpose of testing code that interact with the database and also for tests with the migrations themselves. But every time I run my code an error is returned and some warnings are yell by Gorm:

```
$ DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable" ./txdb_ejemplo
`txdb_postgres` is not officially supported, running under compatibility mode.

(/home/jorge/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/gormigrate.v1@v1.6.0/gormigrate.go:381)
[2019-08-12 19:46:28]  pq: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
panic: migration failed: pq: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /home/jorge/proyectos/kue/fero/txdb_ejemplo/main.go:76 +0x3a1
```

And this is the output of the docker service running offering the database:

```
db_1  | 2019-08-13 01:46:08.788 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1  | 2019-08-13 01:46:28.564 UTC [48] ERROR:  function database() does not exist at character 8
db_1  | 2019-08-13 01:46:28.564 UTC [48] HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
db_1  | 2019-08-13 01:46:28.564 UTC [48] STATEMENT:  SELECT DATABASE()
db_1  | 2019-08-13 01:46:28.564 UTC [48] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AND" at character 71
db_1  | 2019-08-13 01:46:28.564 UTC [48] STATEMENT:  SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = ? AND table_name = ?
db_1  | 2019-08-13 01:46:28.564 UTC [48] ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
db_1  | 2019-08-13 01:46:28.564 UTC [48] STATEMENT:  CREATE TABLE migrations (id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY)
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, but I offer a minimal functional example that reproduces the issue I'm having, [here is the repository with the code](https://github.com/shackra/txdb_ejemplo) and there is a primer of the Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/DATA-DOG/go-txdb"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    gormigrate "gopkg.in/gormigrate.v1"
)

var (
    migration_1 = func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
        type Person struct {
            gorm.Model
            Name string
        }

        return tx.CreateTable(&Person{}).Error
    }
    migration_2 = func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
        type Person struct {
            Age int
        }
        return tx.AutoMigrate(&Person{}).Error
    }
    return_nil = func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
        return nil
    }
)

type Person struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func MigrateAll(gdb *gorm.DB) error {
    m := gormigrate.New(gdb, gormigrate.DefaultOptions, []*gormigrate.Migration{
        {
            ID:       "first",
            Migrate:  migration_1,
            Rollback: return_nil,
        },
        {
            ID:       "second",
            Migrate:  migration_2,
            Rollback: return_nil,
        },
    })
    return m.Migrate()
}

func main() {
    url := os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL")
    txdb.Register("txdb_postgres", "postgres", url)
    var db *gorm.DB
    var err error
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        db, err = gorm.Open("txdb_postgres", "tx_1")
        if err == nil {
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("connection failed, retrying in 10 seconds. Reason: %s\n", err)
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    }
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("connection failed: %s", err))
    }

    defer db.Close()
    err = MigrateAll(db)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("migration failed: %s", err))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seams to be that `gorm` uses the first `gorm.Open` argument as a dialect name (it has a set of predefined dialects) and not as a `database/sql` driver name.

So you need to use a `gorm` known dialect name as the first argument, in this case you want `"postgres"` since you will be using postgresql as the underlying database hence you need `gorm` using the corresponding sql dialect.

Then you tell `gorm` to use the `"txdb"` driver and `"tx_1"` as the connection url.

This seem to work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/DATA-DOG/go-txdb"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    gormigrate "gopkg.in/gormigrate.v1"
)

var (
    migration_1 = func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
        type Person struct {
            gorm.Model
            Name string
        }

        return tx.CreateTable(&Person{}).Error
    }
    migration_2 = func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
        type Person struct {
            Age int
        }
        return tx.AutoMigrate(&Person{}).Error
    }
    return_nil = func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
        return nil
    }
)

type Person struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func MigrateAll(gdb *gorm.DB) error {
    m := gormigrate.New(gdb, gormigrate.DefaultOptions, []*gormigrate.Migration{
        {
            ID:       "first",
            Migrate:  migration_1,
            Rollback: return_nil,
        },
        {
            ID:       "second",
            Migrate:  migration_2,
            Rollback: return_nil,
        },
    })
    return m.Migrate()
}

func main() {
    url := os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL")
    txdb.Register("txdb", "postgres", url)
    var db *gorm.DB
    var err error
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        db, err = gorm.Open("postgres", "txdb", "tx_1")
        if err == nil {
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("connection failed, retrying in 10 seconds. Reason: %s\n", err)
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    }
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("connection failed: %s", err))
    }

    defer db.Close()
    err = MigrateAll(db)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("migration failed: %s", err))
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could pass `gorm.Open` directly the `*sql.Db`, the relevant part would be like:

```
        s, err := sql.Open("txdb", "tx_1")
        // handle err
        db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", s)
        // handle err
```

And that would work too.

Comment: You have saved my skin, thank you! I have updated the example code to reflect the implementation of your answer in two different branches https://github.com/shackra/txdb_ejemplo